# Listing only the directory from AWS S3 using PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following structure in my AWS S3 Buckets.
[image: S3Bucket view]

With this code, I get the listing of ALL the objects under `rootfolder/`
My question is: **How to list all the objects from the first level** (*colored in red.*)
[image: S3Bucket view]

With the following code below, i get an output like:
`rootfolder/hi.pdf rootfolder/creds.txt rootfolder/photo.png rootfolder/folder2/ rootfolder/folder2/creds2.txt rootfolder/folder2/account.pdf`

```
function userlistObjectsSourceFolder() {
    global $s3Client;
    $bucket='myBucketS3';
    
    $objects = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
        "Bucket" => $bucket,
        'Marker' => "rootfolder/",
        "Prefix" => "rootfolder/"


        
    )); 
    foreach ($objects as $object) {

        echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
        
    }
}
```

The desired output would be

`rootfolder/hi.pdf rootfolder/creds.txt rootfolder/photo.png rootfolder/folder2/`

---

**EDIT 2:**
I implemented `ListObjectsV2` as

```
function userlistObjectsSourceFolder($sourceFolder2) {
    global $s3Client;
    $bucket='s3schema-template';
    
    $objects = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjectsV2', array(
        "Bucket" => $bucket
        "Prefix" => "rootfolder/",
        "Delimiter" =>  "/"
        
        

        
    )); 
    foreach ($objects as $object) {

        echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
        

        
    }
```

With this config i get the output:
`rootfolder/ rootfolder/hi.pdf rootfolder/creds.txt rootfolder/photo.png`  
But **I can't manage to return the CommonPrefixes**, which in this case it is `folder2/`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just get the contents of the top folder you can use the `ListObjectsV2` method, and add the `Delimiter` property to your request, with a value of `/`. You should get a set of `Contents` that are just at the root of your prefix, as well as a set of `CommonPrefixes` that will return the "sub folders" (I put that in quotes because they aren't really folders).

Comment: Thanks @Jason Wadsworth for the reply, I will try to achieve what you have posted and come back with the results. Appreciate it ;)

Comment: Hi there @Jason Wadsworth, I tried your idea and I am almost there, in order to list the ``CommonPrefixes`` how could I list the "sub folders", as $object['CommonPrefixes'] maybe? Thanks

Comment: My bad, i was using the getIterator method, sorry for that...

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured how to get the contents of a folder (files AND "subfolders") without having to load up the entire contents of the bucket each time.

First an example array to pass in:

```
$options = array(
    "Bucket" => $bucket,
    "Prefix" => "rootFolder/",
    "Delimiter" =>  "/"
);
```

This creates an Iterator that will only show you the "files":

```
$objects = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjectsV2', $options);
```

so you can only do this (which does not include "folders" because they end with "/"):

```
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    echo '<br>' . $object['Key'] . ' ' . $object['Size'];
} //for
```

Instead, do this to get the whole object passed back:

```
$contents = $s3Client->listObjectsV2($options);
```

Then you get the whole object which contains an array called "Common Prefixes" that looks like this and gives you the "folders":

```
[CommonPrefixes] => Array (
    [0] => Array ([Prefix] => Folder 1/)
    [1] => Array ([Prefix] => Carly/)
 )
```

And you get another array called Contents which is what the getIterator call returns (your files):

```
[Contents] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Key] => rootFolder/myFile.txt
                        [LastModified] => Aws\Api\DateTimeResult Object
                            (
                                [date] => 2021-11-18 08:56:53.000000
                                [timezone_type] => 2
                                [timezone] => Z
                            )

                        [ETag] => "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
                        [Size] => 0
                        [StorageClass] => STANDARD
                    )

                [1] => Array
                ...
```